# Custom tab in Salesforce1 Account record page

Tags: salesforce1-app

I need to create custom tab in salesforce1 app on record page like related,detals,Feed tab in record page. I need a custom tab site information like in lightining. Please see screenshot for better understanding:
[image]

Like in Lightning page i need same thing in salesforce1 page here:
[image]

I search flexi pages but they create a new tab in navigation bar. Is there a way to overide compact layout with flexi pages?. Please any help is appreciated.